# Vesa Problems: 0xA0000 or 0xB0000

Tags: video, virtualbox, vesa

When dealing with Vesa (version 2) I can detect if its available, get all the available resolutions, but when it comes to setting the resolution... I am able to change to 1024x768 (32bpp) but then the screen is just blank... am testing it on VirtualBox...

After setting the mode, is there anything else am supposed to do?

Comment: see [Display an array of color in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214) and look for C++ VESA example you just need to fill the VRAM with some image data ...

Answer (score 4):

Did you actually set any pixels on? It's possible the memory is zeroed out so all you see is an all black screen.

Comment: no all I did was just, change to the mode... it clears all my text and printf no more works

Comment: ... printf works only in text mode. If you want something on the screen in vesa mode you need to draw some pixels manually. On a different note, why the hell are you mocking around with DOS?

Comment: A blank screen is normal after setting the video mode. what you have  to do know is to map the address (if you have paging enabled) and then just write to that address