# How to read image file and display on screen in windows tasm dosbox

Tags: assembly, graphics, tasm, dosbox

Im currently learning graphical programming in tasm using dosbox. Ive been using a bunch of loops to draw square blocks of pixels and its really hard. I want to know if theres a way to read an image and display it. I know how to read a txt file maybe this is a start. Pls help

Comment: No, that's not possible... that's the reason, why all the DOS games did draw just squares, and never had any graphic files with images... /sarcasm ... yes, you "just" load the content of file into memory, if it is compressed file, then you decompress it (writing own gif decoder may be much more difficult then doing bunch of loops), then you copy it to VRAM. Memory management (as you are in real mode? So each memory page only 64ki long and juggling around with segment regs all the time), and palette problems included. (probably easiest way is to prepare "raw" data in file in target format)

Comment: btw, I'm flagging this as "too broad" ... you should at least pick graphics mode (16 colors have completely different format than 256 13h mode), specify real/protected mode (and if you are in real mode, and planning to do anything memory intensive, then rather consider using some "extender" like dos4gw and start using protected mode), and specify gfx file format (choose wisely, as writing decompression routines can be project in itself, if you don't plan to mix with C and some library ... bmp is doable, just upside-down data, and some old formats were even more friendly, just can't recall any)

Comment: I'm using svga mode - 101H  -  640x480   -  256  packed pixel. I've seen some using bitmaps and am trying to learn to read bitmap files and display it

Comment: Ok, `bmp` is reasonably simple to read and decode, although in real mode with 64ki segments it will be total PITA to operate in such high resolution. Actually I can't even recall how that SVGA mode memory layout is designed and what is banked, if every 4th pixel (nah, doesn't fit), or every bit over 8 planes, or just the whole screen is divided into 5+ parts. (I used Watcom C compiler to init everything into protected mode, load files, decode them, etc (all in C/C++), and VBE2.0 extension to have linear protected mode VRAM mapping, then I did the fun stuff in 32b asm, so everything was simple)

Answer (score 3):

You need to write/use image loader or use your own image file format. **BMP** may look simple but has too much in it like compression pixel formats etc but you still can focus on a specific type of **BMP** and ignore all the others...

Back in the days of **MS-DOS** I was using 256 color **PCX** images with palette as I used 256 color video modes. Here **NASM LINEZ** game example:

- [Color Lines - simple game in C++/the checking algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45583938/2521214)

see the `pcx:` subroutine. It decodes loaded **PCX** file from memory `ds:0` to raw **VGA** image at `es:di`. Beware it does support just `64 KByte` size limit !!!
Now to visualize the image you would have to copy `es:di` content into **VideoRAM** (assuming `A000:0000`) for example with `rep movsd` or you can set `es:di` to it in the first place (but that could flicker).

This **PCX** loader however does not use palette from the image so you need to encode it ... (the routines to change **VGA** palette are included in the source you just need to extract the **RGB** values from **PCX** I think it was at the end of file) Look here:

- [my C++ PCX loader with palette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37340970/2521214)

if converts PCX to 32bit raw image.

For more info about **MS-DOS** game programing see [PCGPE 1.0](https://www.pcorner.com/list/UPLOAD/PCGPE.ZIP/INFO/)

Here another game example (**TASM**) which uses own image file-format:

- [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214)

It has text menues, binary file access, 320x200 sprite graphics, 3 human players

**[Edit1] New code**

I removed the old code example and instead I created compilable and working 8bit **PCX** with color palette viewer in **TASM**. It uses **VESA** `800x600x256` colors mode (`103h`).

**The image must fit into screen and its file size must be less than 64 KByte !!!**

I did not add any checks or error messages ... It simply loads file `image.pcx` and displays it on **VESA** then wait on key hit end exit. Here the **TASM** source:

**PCX.ASM**

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    .386
    IDEAL
    MODEL TINY
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    DATASEG
file:   db 'image.pcx',0    ;filename to load
buff:       
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    CODESEG
    STARTUPCODE

    scrxs   equ 800
    scrys   equ 600
    mov ax,103h ; VESA 800x600x256
    call    vesamod
    mov al,0
    call    vesapag

;   scrxs   equ 320
;   scrys   equ 200
;   mov ax,19   ; VGA 320x200x256
;   int 10h

    lea dx,[file]   ; load PCX into DS:buff, CX bytes
    call    fopen
    lea dx,[buff]
    mov cx,64000    ; some max value to fit into DS segment
    call    fread       ; CX is PCX real size
    call    fclose

    lea si,[buff]   ; decode directly to VRAM
    mov ax,0A000h
    mov es,ax
    mov di,0
    call    pcx
mainl0:
    mov ax,256  ; test keyboard
    int 16h
    jz  mainl0
    sub ax,ax   ; clear key buffer
    int 16h

    mov ax,3    ;|VGA 80x25 text
    int 16
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
vesamod:pusha               ;set VESA videomode ax
    mov     bx,ax
    mov     ax,4f02h
    int     16
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
vesapag:pusha               ;al=page  switch vesa video page window A
    mov [cs:scrpag],al
    mov     dl,al
    sub     dh,dh
    sub     bx,bx
    mov     ax,4f05h    ; window A
    int     16
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  .386P
scrpag  db 0
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;  .386P
hand    dw 0        ;###    handler...
ferr    db 0        ;###    DOS error code
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fopen:  pusha       ;DS:DX = file name, [hand] <= file handle
    mov ax,3D02h
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fopen0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fopen0: mov [cs:hand],ax
    mov [cs:ferr],bl
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fclose: pusha       ;[hand] = file handle
    mov bx,[cs:hand]
    mov ah,3eh
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fclose0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fclose0:mov [cs:ferr],bl
    mov [cs:hand],ax
    popa
    ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
fread:  pusha       ;DS:DX = adr, CX = lenght, [hand] = hand, CX => read
    mov bx,[cs:hand]
    mov ah,3Fh
    int 21h
    mov bl,0
    jnc fread0
    mov bl,al
    sub ax,ax
fread0: mov [cs:ferr],bl
    mov [cs:freadsz],ax
    popa
    mov cx,[cs:freadsz]
    ret
freadsz dw 0
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
pcx:    pusha           ;decode pcx at ds:si to es:di cx = PCX size
    push    ds
    push    es
    push    ecx
    push    edx

    push    si      ;set palette
    add si,cx
    sub si,768
    sub ax,ax   
pall0:  mov dx,3C8h
    mov al,ah
    out dx,al
    inc dx
    lodsb
    shr al,2
    out dx,al
    lodsb
    shr al,2
    out dx,al
    lodsb
    shr al,2
    out dx,al
    inc ah
    jnz pall0
    pop si

    mov ax,[ds:si+8]    ;get xs
    sub ax,[ds:si+4]
    inc ax
    mov [cs:pcxxs],ax
    mov [cs:pcxx],ax

    mov ax,[ds:si+10]   ;get ys
    sub ax,[ds:si+6]
    inc ax
    mov [cs:pcxys],ax   

    mul [cs:pcxxs]
    push    dx
    push    ax
    pop edx
    add si,128      ;src start after pcx header
    sub ecx,ecx     ;RLE decoder of PCX
pcxl0:  lodsb
    mov cx,1
    cmp al,192
    jb  pcxr0
    mov cl,al
    and cl,63
    lodsb
pcxr0:  mov bx,cx
pcxl1:  call    point

    dec [cs:pcxx]   ;correct next screen line position if end of PCX line
    jnz pcxr1   
    mov ax,[cs:pcxxs]
    mov [cs:pcxx],ax
    neg ax
    add ax,scrxs
    add di,ax
    jnc pcxr1
    ; page swith
    mov al,[cs:scrpag]
    inc al
    call    vesapag

pcxr1:  loop    pcxl1
    mov cx,bx
    sub edx,ecx
    jz  pcxesc
    jnc pcxl0

pcxesc: pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop es
    pop ds
    popa
    ret
pcxxs   dw  0   ;PCX resolution
pcxys   dw  0
pcxx    dw  0   ;actual X coordinate 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
point:  mov [es:di],al      ;point      ;estosb 
    inc di
    jnz pntesc
    ; page swith
    mov al,[cs:scrpag]
    inc al
    call    vesapag
pntesc: ret
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
    END
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

So take any image up to `800x600` convert it to 256 color PCX with palette and rename it to `image.pcx`. Then place it to your `*.com` file and run. I compiled it with Volcov commander extension script `vc.ext` like this:

```
asm:@c:\language\compil\tasm\tasm !.! /ic:\language\source\tasm\inc
    @c:\language\compil\tasm\tlink !.obj /t /x
    @del !.obj
```

so each time I hit the enter on any asm file it will compile. Just change the paths and if you are not targeting `*.com` files then change the `/t` switch accordingly. Here preview from my **DOSBox**:

[image: preview]

Comment: By the way, how do i print string with larger fonts in graphics mode. I'm using now 800x600 256 colors.

Comment: writing an image loader maybe too much for me for the time being, i'll stick with drawing block by block of pixels. Thank you for teaching me some ideas

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe use larger font or double the pixels The fonts can be obtained from EGA/VGA ROM or use image like this [ASCII 8x8 pixel 32x8 characters font texture](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44797902/2521214). For the loader it is enough to copy the pcx routine of mine and use it on file loaded into memory. for more then 64KB you need to add page switchings ... either by VESA BIOS or use LFB .... but that is more suited for Protected mode which I do not have experience with ...

Comment: How? i don't understand, isn't there just a function in the video services that   would make the font size increase? I've tried ah = 1122h, 1123h, 1124h, in int 10h and the font size were larger indeed but were distorted and not readable. i don't know

Comment: im sorry but i can't comprehend some of the stuff that you mentioned  like the loader or the pcx routine

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe 1. in gfx mode you should use your own string print functions. 2. search the code block in my answer for `pcx:` it is pcx decoder to raw 256 color image without palette. So you need just copy its source to your project and call it with the registers set ... it needs just the file loaded in memory which you can do as you mention you can open text files and as destination chose some memory or use VRAM directly. It is written for 320x200x256 video mode so start with that and when working you can recode to 800x600 or whatever

Comment: are the video pages, in int 10h similar to layers in programs like photoshop? wherein the graphics on 1 page is independent of the other? I'm drawing some static graphics in page 0, then I'm drawing graphics in page 1 which will be movable, how do i clear page 1, without affecting other pages? 

I've tried, selecting the active page 1, then draw black in the whole screen, then select active page 0 again. but the graphics drawn on page 0 are not returning.

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe Pages on VESA are just 64KByte parts of screen they are not move-able (if I remember correctly) They are there because you can address only 64 KBytes  from VRAM but the videomode requires more ... `800x600x256-> 7x64KByte`. If you are in protected mode then you can access the whole VRAM if map as LFB into CPU memory space but that is way above my knowledge (I used only real mode)

Comment: my method for moving graphics will be, delete previous graphic, increment position, then draw again. i'm thinking of clearing the whole screen in video page 1, to delete the previous graphic. While the contents in video page 0 will still remain and be visible, then draw again

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe you are mixing pages with back/double buffering  those are not the same thing ...

Comment: sorry i have a lot of misconceptions, one more question.
In C++ you can create header files, and use them in another cpp file. 
Is there a way to implement this in assembly?

like i have "mainProgram.asm", then i want to create "subProgram.asm"  and subProgram contains many many procedures and macros. and i want to include them in mainProgram like #include <subProgram.asm> or something. Is it possible to do this? Because my code is getting very long and it's hard to manage

Comment: I've seen some using include "filename.inc"
what is this .inc file? is this what i need to implement what i said in previously^? how to do this?

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe you can use `include 'filename'` directive ... the `*.asm, *.inc; *.lib` extensions are used all are in `asm`.

Comment: in my mainProgram.asm, i have .model .data, .stack, .code. in my subProgram.asm, i also have them, i tried using "include subProgram.asm" it assembled, but when i call a procedure from the subProgram.asm in mainProgram.asm, it doesn't work.

Comment: HOLY SH**T, I SUCCESSFULLY INCLUDED AN ASM FILE, I REMOVED THE THE DIRECTIVES IN MY SUBPROGRAM AND JUST LEFT THE .CODE THERE AND IT WORK HOLY SH**T. THANK YOU MAN

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe yes directives in subfiles mess things up as you got them in the main file too which conflicts them in between ... the `include` just copies the file to that place where the `include` is (just like in C++) so you need to be careful with using DATA and CODE segments in included files ... Btw I tried to compile the pcx decoder under TASM but it does not work due to compiler incompatibilities (it was written in NASM) I must have forgot to change something that TASM does not like ... aaargh I hate TASM now I remember why I moved to NASM ....

Comment: @JhonPaulJaspe added edit1  finaly found the problem with TASM (datasegment labels does not start  at offset 0 and also got the direct memory addressing going)