# Graphics/Character Sprite in Intel 8086 Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86-16

So I'm working on a final project for my assembly language class (using Intel 8086 Assembly Language and DOSBox) and I want to incorporate some sort of little graphic in my program. Specifically, I'm wanting to make a little character sprite of a Pokémon, but I don't know where to even start learning how to do this. Can anyone tell me where I should look to learn how to do this and what this would even be called? Thank you in advance!

Comment: DOSBox can emulate an x86 with VGA graphics, so you can use normal bitmapped graphics like you'd put in a `.bmp` or `.ppm` image.

Answer (score 1):

see

- [What is the best way to move an object on the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29579522/2521214)

its a simple ancient unfinished (but playable) game of mine for MS-DOS in asm that uses text mode for menus and gfx mode with sprites for the game itself ... it covers things like:

- key redefine
- keyboard 2D movement control (using ISR so you can pres multiple keys at once)
- map overlay
- status indicators
- file handling
- 256 color 320x200 gfx and 80x25 text VGA modes

Also see these:

- [Graphics mode in assembly 8086](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664419/2521214)
- [show PCX in MS-DOS asm in VESA mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780565/2521214)

That should cover all you need for your project. Anyway If you want more you should dive into Interrupts and HW registers in MS-DOS as most of the peripherrals communicate through them (keyboard, PIT, VGA/VESA/VBE, OS, ... ) and provides things like file handling, access to EMS,XMS, timing,....

The most comprehensive tutorial on all things involved I have seen is:

- [PCGPE 1.0](https://www.pcorner.com/list/UPLOAD/PCGPE.ZIP/INFO/)

Which is **PC Game Programmer Encyklopedia 1.0** in full name and it covers all of the above and much much more. Its an MS-DOS app viewing the topics (so you need DosBox or MS-DOS). There are also Windows help ports of this but the links I got are dead and too lazy to google them again...